# Prove that $\|{e^{At}x_o}\| \geq e^{-\lambda t}\|{x_o}\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Prove that $\|{e^{At}x_o}\| \geq e^{-\lambda t}\|{x_o}\|$, for some $\lambda \gt 0$, A is $n\times n$ matrix and $x_o$ is a $n \times 1$ vector.

Comment: I'm guessing you want this proved forall $t \geq 0$, $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (or maybe $x_0 \in \mathbb{C}^n$?), but you should really state the explicitly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $\|x_0\|_2=\|e^{-At}e^{At}x_0\|_2\leq \|e^{-At}\|_2\|e^{At}x_0\|_2$.

Now, $\|e^{-At}\|_2\leq e^{\|At\|_2}=e^{\lambda t}$,  where $\lambda:=\|A\|_2$. Notice that if $A$ is nonzero, then $\lambda>0$.

It's not clear what norm you want here, but the same proof should work for any consistant norm, that is: $\|Ax\|\leq \|A\|\|x\|$

Comment: thanks Alex and fgp. I ended up doing the same thing but was initially thrown off course since I didn't realize that $||e^{-At}||\leq e^{||At||}$